# Copy/ Move list item from one list to another based on "assigned to" field sharepoint 2007/2010

Tags: list, sharepoint

I have a requirement where in the user enters a ticket using the ticketing list in sharepoint 2007 and IT manager assigns the list item/ticket based on the ticket description etc to programmer/ network admin etc
Now our network team is asking me to create a network list for which the users don't have access to create, instead this list gets its items from the helpdesk ticket list when IT manager assigns it to a certain person/persons. When the ticket is assigned to person x(in network team), the ticket should move automatically to the network list. When network team takes care of this ticket and closes it or any other status changes, then users should get notified directly.

I use sharepoint 2007.

Comment: your question is hard to read

Comment: Hi There, I have a requiremetn to move/ copy a list item from one list in a subsite to another list in another subsite.